# galaxy s3 not charging

Tags: battery, charging

I have a samsung galaxy s3. It is only 7 months old. Its battery is not getting charged. I have tried to reboot and take the battery out and put it again,it still doesnt get charged. The usb port is not faulty as others phones get charged from it. What should I do?

Comment: Did any of the answers below solve your problem. If so, please mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Again, any help from the answers below? Did you also try different chargers and cables?

Answer (score 1):

I think the USB port of your phone is defective. IMO it's best you get it replaced while warranty is still active(Samsung offers one year warranty)

Comment: This is likely to be the case. To confirm, hook the S3 to your computer and see if it shows up as a device.

Answer (score 1):

Try too clean the plug on your phone with a thin needle or brush.
I had the same problem than you did, and clening it up solved the problem

You can have a look there:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6p0Eg-yq3A.

If you to this cautiously with proper tools, there is no risk for you to damage the phone.